# Как использовать return в тернарном операторе

Tags: php

```
finction test($id){
    if(!$id){
      return false;
    }
    // обработка id
}
```

Я не очень понимаю что поставить в первую часть выражения что бы скрипт продолжил работу. Пробовал так:

```
(!$id) ? return false : ;
```

Не прокатило

Comment: `return ($id) ? : false;` или `return (!$id) ? false : true;` -  в зависимости от версии языка и от того нужно ли возвращать true

Comment: @АлексейШиманский первое что нужно, спасибо

Comment: либо `return (boolean) $id;`, если и `true` нужно

Comment: finction test($id){
      return !!$id;
} а лучше вообще без функции

Comment: Похоже, мы все прозевали ключевую фразу, "чтобы скрипт продолжил работу"

Answer (score 1):

> чтобы скрипт продолжил работу

Ничего не поставить, тернарный оператор здесь не подходит.

Надо использовать обычный условный переход

```
if (!$id) return;
```

Comment: В реальности это метод внутри класса, поэтому если выражение неудачное метод обязан сделать return false и таким образом прервать своё дальнейшее выполнение. Пока в вашем ответе нет тернарного условия о котором идёт речь в вопросе.

Comment: Разумеется нет, поскольку никакого тернарного события в данном случае нет, есть банальная бинарная двухходовка.

Comment: Так если он просто делает `if (!$id) return;` то придёт true? Или false т.к. после return ничего нет

Comment: С какой стати там придет true? Ничего нет, поэтому ничего и не придет.

Comment: А нужно что бы false пришёл

Comment: Нет, это не нужно.